# How to read large list of JSON objects into Python

Tags: python, json, list

I have a large file (130gb) saved which is a single list containing millions of JSON objects formatted as follows:

```py
[{...},{...},{...},...,{...}]
```

How would I iterate over each JSON object one at a time?
I have tried:

```py
with open(filename,'r') as file:
    for row in file:
        json.loads(row)
```

However this does not work.

Thanks!

Comment: I think that's the main issue with the JSON format compared to CSV for instance. The whole file has to be loaded in order to have a meaning. Maybe you could "cheat" a bit by transforming you file into `jsonl` first (see https://jsonlines.org/)? This is meant to solve this exact issue. Then you could read and parse the file line by line. This would of course only work if your data is has one item per line.

Comment: You can only use your code if your file has exactly one JSON value per line. The `json` module doesn't support streaming; you have to read the entire file into memory first. You want a third-party module like `ijson` (no endorsement, just the first one that came to mind) to "lazily" parse the JSON file.